# Use Qt Design Studio QML with PySide2

Tags: python, qml, qtquick2, pyside2, qt-design-studio

I am new to Qt Designer Studio. I just created a simple button in Qt Design Studio and I am trying to use the QML file with PySide2 but I am getting multiple import errors. Is there a specific way to implement Qt Design Studio qml files with PySide2.

The project name is Demo that I created in Qt Design Studio

The Demo Project structure:

```
   Demo.qml
   Demo.qmlproject
   Demo.qmlproject.qtds
   imports
   qtquickcontrols2.conf
   Screen01.ui.qml
```

The PySide2 project structure (main.py files includes the code):

```
   Demo.qml
   Demo.qmlproject
   Demo.qmlproject.qtds
   imports
   qtquickcontrols2.conf
   Screen01.ui.qml
   main.py
```

main.py:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from imports import QtQuick
app = QApplication([])
view = QQuickView()
url = QUrl("Screen01.ui.qml")
view.engine().addImportPath("imports")
view.setSource(url)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Error:

```
module "QtStudio3D" is not installed 
module "Qt.SafeRenderer" is not installed
```

Screen01.ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import Demo 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Rectangle {
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height

    color: Constants.backgroundColor

    Button {
        id: nameButton
        x: 136
        y: 227
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @eylianesc. I have updated the question with the content of Screen01.ui.qml. Please do have a look.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PTEjTnmqLbVHTDXqclzYowByT9DSrRub @eyllanesc

Comment: It is giving these two errors when I am using it on a CentOS system. module "QtStudio3D" is not installed and module "Qt.SafeRenderer" is not installed. Also, how can I interact with the button on the user interface and when I am using a full screen on the design in Qt DS it shows part of the application screen white.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207915/discussion-between-pratik-tayshete-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: I am using PySide2==5.14.1

Comment: I am also not able to find a way to interact with the button in the user interface and not able to make the application full screen

Comment: I am having the same error on the centOS system that I am using but I also installed Qt DS on my laptop where I am not getting that error

Comment: How can we connect the widgets (Button) made in Qt DS inside PySide2?

Comment: @eylianesc, I am not getting the import errors now but I am not able to use the widgets made using Qt Design Studio in PySide2

Comment: Hi! can you provide some example code that interact between PySide2 and QtDesignStudio Qml files?

Answer (score 0):

Use [PyQt](https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python) and Qt Designer to create a UI

Answer (score 0):

For ppl stumbling here with googling i got main window to show properly with:

```
import sys
import os

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QObject, Signal, Slot, Property
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
     
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.addImportPath("imports")
    print(engine.importPathList() )
    engine.load('qttest2.qml')
    
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the file qttest2.qml is from qt design studio, containing (had to edit manually for the main window):

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import qttest2 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
  visible: true
  width: 800
  height: 500
  Item {
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height

    Screen01 {
    }
  }
}
```